# Android 5.0 (API Level 21) AVD not launching Intel Atom x86_64

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Does anybody else have this problem with the recently released SDK (V23.0.5 / Windows 7)?

Interestingly I can start Google APIs 21 on Intel Atom x86_64, so I do not see a general issue. Normal Android 5.0 does not work. Emulator comes up, but keeps showing a blank screen.

Comment: what SDK Tools do you have?

Comment: I've experienced the same issue. I did get the API 21 x86 (32 bit) emulator working after installing the new HAXM. But still can't start the _64 flavor.

Comment: Same here, and x86 bits crash's after a short time using it, im on Mac and you guys ?

Comment: SDK 23.0.5 on Win 7. API 21 x86 works, Google API 21 x86_64 works, but not API 21 x86_64

Answer (score 3):

Updating HAXM to the latest version (Version 1.1.0 preview release 2 at the moment of speaking) should solve all problems related to the Intel Atom images.

Comment: I can not find a version 2. Google APIs Intel Atom is V2. Normal Intel Atom Images (32 /64 Bit) are still on V1 (API 21). Which could explain the crashes on normal HAXM.

Comment: I was talking about haxm, not the system images. The latest version can be fetched from the sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

if your sdks are up to date just check your cpus patch for avd system if you dont have an intel one you need to download avd patch driver from AMD website