# How to resolve error message: "This AVD may not work unless you install...first"?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to create an AVD for Android 5, but it's giving me a warning

> This AVD may not work unless you install the Google APIs Intel Atom (x86) system image for Android 5.0 (API 21) first.

But I have that installed - this is a screenshot of my SDK manager with the correct System Images installed:

[image]

And this is how I'm configuring my AVD:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get this to work?

Comment: may be cause android SDK build  tools , update it to 21 or higher

Comment: I'll give that a try.. I didn't think the build tools would influence the AVD though.

Comment: check that also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474318/android-5-0-api-level-21-avd-not-launching-intel-atom-x86-64

Comment: try change CPU its work with me

Comment: yeah it works when I use the ARM cpu but I want Intel because it's much faster. I tried updating the HAXM as per your link but it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: i use Genymotion emulator is much faster than eclipse one , may you like to try it

Comment: did you try to simply ignore the message?

Answer (score 2):

Install Android SDK Build-tools 21 or higher
and check Use Host GPU

[image]

Comment: I've installed all the missing build tools, and updated HAXM to 1.1.1 and I'm still seeing the message, and the AVD still doesn't start.

Comment: if not works switch your emulator target to Android 5.0  without google APi

Comment: specifying the Host GPU worked in the sense that the AVD runs now, but I'm still seeing the warning. As such, I'll upvote the answer but I can't mark it as correct. It seems to be very flaky software.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to resolve this issue manually...waiting for a fix by Big G:

Searching between all the various .ini files generated by Android AVD Manager, I found 
***hardware-qemu.ini***
(its location is %USER_FOLDER%/.android/avd/***yourAVDName***.avd/hardware-qemu.ini).
It contains a row starting with ***kernel.path*** pointing to the wrong google apis location.
 Once changed it with the right one 

(e.g. *path_to_android_sdk*/system-images\android-19\google_apis\x86/kernel-qemu for Google API 19 version)
the emulator started with the right Android version, containing Google APIs.

Hope this helps all Android developers :D

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but hardware-qemu.ini in my case got overwritten with the old value at every emulator start. I had to change config.ini in the same folder and here 'image.sysdir.1' with the correct imagepath before the very first start of the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the HAXM driver on your machine in addition to downloading the components.  This step is done outside the Android tools.